# How to install specific versions of Google Chrome / Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google, testing

I'm looking for standalone packages for Google Chrome / Chromium which can be extracted and used as binaries for my [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) test suite.

How do I go about such a thing?

Comment: Relevant Question: [Download older versions of Google Chrome for Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11408325/1254292)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the issue of being required to run a specific version of Chrome on Linux to reproduce a bug that was reported to me. As at the time, the official downloads didn't offer this version any longer (and searching for a solution didn't give me one, I asked [here](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msgid/chrome/0fc475f4-3a6c-4102-bd39-0614db889ddf%40googleproductforums.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer)). I have received a very helpful answer there, which liked to https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium

I'll copy/paste the relevant steps from that page here:

> **Downloading old builds of Chrome / Chromium**
>
> Let's say you want a build of Chrome 44 for debugging purposes. Google
>   does not offer old builds as they do not have up-to-date security
>   fixes.
>
> However, you can get a build of Chromium 44.x which should mostly
>   match the stable release.  Here's how you find it:
>
> - Look in https://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/search/label/Stable%20updates for the last time "44." was mentioned.
> - Loop up that version history ("44.0.2403.157") in the [Position Lookup](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/)
> - In this case it returns a base position of "330231". This is the commit of where the 44 release was branched, back in May 2015. (see footnote)
> - Open the continuous builds archive
> - Click through on your platform (Linux/Mac/Win)
> - Paste "330231" into the filter field at the top and wait for all the results to XHR in.
> - Eventually I get a perfect hit: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/330231/
>     -- Sometimes you may have to decrement the commit number until you find one.
> - Download and run!
>
> footnote: As this build was made at 44 branch point, it does not have any commits merged in while in beta.  Typically that's OK, but if you need
>   a true build of "44.0.2403.x" then you'll need to build Chromium from
>   the 2403 branch. Some PortableApps/PortableChromium sites offer
>   binaries like this, due to security concerns, the Chrome team does not
>   recommend running them.

Answer (score 1):

"The open-source Chromium continuous builds are archived at http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html  .". source: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/Z-UroWhOhX0

Comment: Link is dead now

Answer (score 0):

Standalone packages for Google Chrome can be found at the following links:

---

**64bit Ubuntu**

http://www.google.com/chrome/thankyou.html?hl=en&platform=linux_ubuntu_x86_64

**32bit Ubuntu**

http://www.google.com/chrome/thankyou.html?hl=en&platform=linux_ubuntu_i386

Source: **[Google Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/4K-po26x1mk/fNExJmJ6-3UJ)**

---

***For development, you may however prefer to download and build Chromium.***  [Chromium.org](http://www.chromium.org/Home) documents this process for you [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions), with the source code found [here](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code).

Comment: These are the standard packages which will be automatically updated (the package installs the Google repositories). I guess the OP wanted to install specific versions.

Comment: Is the last paragraph more suited to the question?

Comment: Sort of, but that requires him to build all old releases - question states *packages*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
apt-get install <package name>=<version>

e.g.
apt-get install subversion-tools=1.3.2-5~bpo1
```

?

You can check version for example here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/google-chrome-stable

Answer (score 0):

Note: Your selenium webdriver is using a specific version based upon your normal command of

```
webdriver-manager update
```

When you run webdriver-manager with your command of

```
webdriver-manager start
```

make sure to note which version it is using, you'll see something like

```
/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_76.0.3809.12
```

as part of the logging in console
Now with the known version selenium will be using, you can install the proper binaries for chrome using the link provided by gertvdijk  above [link for different versions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11408325/1254292).
Then to answer the question the install can be something like :

```
#centos
sudo yum -y install google-chrome-stable
#ubuntu
apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score -2):

[http://95.31.35.30/chrome/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/]

it should be a Google Chrome dir on www.oldapps.com

> http://www.oldapps.com/linux/category/browsers

seems google chrome hates older chrome.
for natty, the latest working version of Chrome x64 that does not ask gconf-service it's:
google-chrome-stable_27.0.1453.110-r202711_amd64.deb

if you followed other tutorials & failed.

> http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/482

Ubuntu 11.04 - the Natty Narwhal - released in April 2011 and supported until October 2012.