# Google Chrome cursor and text selection issues after upgrading to google-chrome-stable_41.0.2272.76-1_amd64

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I upgraded from google-chrome-stable_40.0.2214.95-1_amd64
to google-chrome-stable_41.0.2272.76-1_amd64 (automatic update on
Ubuntu MATE 14.04 64 bit) and the mouse text selection stopped working 
and the cursor icons did not change when hovering over links in the
updated browser, also got an annoying 'Enter you password to unlock
login keyring' prompt when Chrome started.

To eliminate the distro from the mix I also upgraded Google Chrome on
Xubuntu 14.04 64-bit from  Google Chrome 39.0.2171.95-1 to
41.0.2272.76-1 and ran into the same problem.

I tried reinstalling the browser:

```
  sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
  rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
  wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

But the problem still persisted so I downgraded back to the previous
version, this worked, the problems dishappeared:

```
  sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
  rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
  sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_40.0.2214.95-1_amd64.deb
```

Older versions of Google Chrome can be downloaded from
http://mirror.pcbeta.com/google/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/

See also:

- [how do I downgrade google chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485856/how-do-i-downgrade-google-chrome)
- http://ubuntuportal.com/2014/04/how-to-install-google-chrome-web-browser-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr.html

Comment: If you don't have a question as such (you have already solved it), you can add your answer (after 'the problem persisted' probably) in the box below. This site and other StackExchange uses a Question and Answer(s) format, it isn't like your usual forum. Also, it would be a good idea to temporarily go back to the version 41 and [report the issue](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315) so it can be fixed. Also, a possibly more trustworthy source is [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/google-chrome-stable) ([source](http://askubuntu.com/q/243394/178596))

Comment: I suppose rolling it back is a solution but I my post was an implicit "am I missing something here?" and "this may save someone else some time". I had posted the issue to Google but have not yet received a response. Yes, your source is possibly more trustworthy.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Stuart, could you please submit a link to the chrome issue you posted? I'd like to get updated when it's fixed.

Comment: I submitted it from the browser menu, you don't get any link just a 'Thank you'. I've just taken a look at the Chrome forum and see the same issue reported here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/chrome/text$20selection%7Csort:date/chrome/LtjX-F6qkwo/grVSBozMFboJ and here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3Kvz9eGm87M

Comment: Seems to be VirtualBox related, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456222

Comment: Thank you for posting this, it's really been pissing me off

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the workaround?

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/google-chrome.desktop.bak~
sudo sed -i 's/\/usr\/bin\/google\-chrome\-stable/\/usr\/bin\/google\-chrome\-stable \-\-touch\-devices=123/g' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

If this workaround causes problems, use this command to uninstall:

```
sudo cp ~/google-chrome.desktop.bak~ /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456222#c175

Answer (score 0):

For me i had to disable hardware acceleration from chrome advanced settings. Debian jessie + mate desktop. Not sure if the --touch-devices=123 was required in my case.

Answer (score -2):

The very same problem which made me to shift on to firefox. It's good but google guys have fixed the problem.
You can try instead the latest version available for firefox as it's far more impressive than Chrome.
http://mozilla_firefox.en.downloadastro.com/

Comment: This URL links to an EXE file which is of no use.